# Django saving a html page as a session

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm quite new to django and presently working a project that requires the final output to be a report displayed on the webpage using the html template,I also have got User authentication built in.I want to be able to save the final output(report on the webpage) as a persistent session associated with the user logged in,such that whenever the user gets logged in again he can have access to previous saved html report-page and get it called up over and over again.

I have session included in the setting and installed app
setting.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',)
```

Model.py

```
class sample_model(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    college = models.ForeignKey('othersample', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        freturn self.number + ': ' + self.name
```

Comment: Can you show the views handling this feature? Im not sure what you're trying to do here.... Do you want to save data and retrieve data from a model ?

Comment: What can't you save HTML as another field in user model or by creating session model with one to one relation with user model?

Comment: The session is not an appropriate place for saving things in the long term.

Comment: Hi Daniel what option do you suggest